# Why we need to define MAVEN_HOME and M2_HOME environment variables

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Why do we need to define MAVEN_HOME and M2_HOME environment variables while both locate the same location till Bin folder?

Comment: yes you are correct, i got my answer, thanks.

Comment: If you are using Maven 3+ you should not use M2_HOME nor MAVEN_HOME anymore and it is not necessary. Only the bin path of the Maven installation must be in PATH nothing more...

Comment: Thanks for reply.